# Performance of C++ based python implementation of Google Protobuf

Tags: c++, python, protocol-buffers

I am using Google Protobuf in my Python application. Experimenting with the protobufs  I found that Protobuf Message Creation is much slower in CPP based python implementation as compared to Python based Python implementation.

Message creation with PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=cpp was upto 2-3 times slower as compared to pure python based Protobuf Message Creation.

Is this expected? I found that SerializeToString and ParseFromString both are faster in the cpp verison. The difference in each case widens as the size of the Message increases.

I am using python's standard timeit module to time these tasks.

(Using Version 2.4.1 of google protobuf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I believe this is expected.  The pure-Python implementation stores all the fields in a dict.  To construct a new message, it essentially just creates an empty dict, which is very fast.  The C++ implementation actually initializes a C++ `DynamicMessage` object under the hood and then wraps it.  `DynamicMessage` actually initializes all of the fields upfront, so even though it's implemented in C++, it's "slower" -- but this upfront initialization makes later operations faster.

I believe you can improve performance further by compiling C++ versions of your protobuf objects and loading them in as another extension.  If I recall correctly, the C++-backed Python protobuf implementation will then automatically used the compiled versions rather than `DynamicMessage`.

Comment: Is there any documentation as to how to do that?  I did compile my protobuf objects with --cpp_out method, but how do I use this in my python application as "another extension"?

Comment: Found http://yz.mit.edu/wp/fast-native-c-protocol-buffers-from-python/ that describes in somewhat more detail what you have pointed out. Thanks!

Comment: Though it didnt really work for me as expected. I was unable to build and use cpp implementations of my .proto files